# Retrieve objects in Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle-type

I have a Oracle object called `Menu` which has a object type as an attribute.

**menu type**

`Create Type Menu as Object(
   beer REF beertype,
   price float
 )`

**beertype**

`Create Type beertype as object(
 name char(20),
 seller char(20)
 )`

**table created using menu type**

```
Create table Sells of Menu
```

**table created using beertype**

```
Create table beer of beertype
```

Now what I want to do is I want to write a select query which retrieves the name of the beer which has price more than 3.5.

I tried

```
SELECT beer.name 
FROM Sells;
```

and

```
SELECT Sells.beer.name 
FROM Sells;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's an example: test case first:

```
SQL> create type beertype as object(
  2    name char(20),
  3    seller char(20)
  4  );
  5  /

Type created.

SQL> create type menu as object(
  2    beer ref beertype,
  3    price float
  4  );
  5  /

Type created.

SQL> create table sells of menu;

Table created.

SQL> create table beer of beertype;

Table created.

SQL> insert into beer (name, seller) values ('Heineken', 'KTC');

1 row created.

SQL> insert into beer (name, seller) values ('Tuborg', 'Plodine');

1 row created.

SQL> insert into sells (beer, price) values ((select ref(b) from beer b where name = 'Heineken'), 10);

1 row created.

SQL> insert into sells (beer, price) values ((select ref(b) from beer b where name = 'Tuborg'), 2.5);

1 row created.
```

Query which selects beer name whose price is larger than 3.5:

```
SQL> select b.name, s.price
  2  from sells s join beer b on value(b) = deref(s.beer)
  3  where s.price > 3.5;

NAME                      PRICE
-------------------- ----------
Heineken                     10

SQL>
```

Here's a nice article, if you want to read more: [Using REF Values for Retrieval of Data Values](https://community.toadworld.com/platforms/oracle/w/wiki/4605.using-ref-values-for-retrieval-of-data-values-oid2)

Comment: It works, I wanna know one more thing. Is it possible to write select query without using join in my case?

Comment: As far as I can tell, no (if you want to select both NAME and PRICE).

Comment: `SELECT s.beer.name, s.price FROM Sells s;` I just found an article mentioning something like this. Currently I am unable to check whether it works or not. What's your opinion

Comment: That's great news for me since I am not that much familiar with `join`. Thank you anyway ;-)

Comment: You're welcome; I'm glad if you'll manage to solve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to use a `JOIN` to get the name; you can just use `DEREF` or chain the reference/attribute names in the `SELECT` clause:

```sql
select DEREF(s.beer).name AS name, s.price
from   sells s
where  s.price > 3.5;
```

or

```sql
select s.beer.name AS name, s.price
from   sells s
where  s.price > 3.5;
```

*(The first option makes it clear that you are de-referencing a `REF` whereas the second option is more concise.)*

Which outputs:

> ```
> NAME                 | PRICE
> :------------------- | ----:
> Heineken             |    10
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=1104828780fd4ceb26c3769f20e3ed00)*